# Is this $W_{r} = \frac{1}{2}kx^2 $ procedure correct

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

I have a $0.40 Kg$ of mass that has $v= 0.5 m/s$, and then crashes with a spring with  constant $k = 750N/m$

Whats the distance that the spring was compressed?

I was using the equation $W_{r} =  \frac{1}{2}kx^2 $

so

$\frac{1}{2}(0.4)(0.5*0.5) = \frac{1}{2}(750)(x^2)$

so $x = 0.011 m$

Is this correct? what is the solution?

Comment: Hi cMinor - generally we discourage questions that just ask for someone to check your work. Once you have identified the specific concept that you're not sure about, that's the point at which it's appropriate to ask a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Corrected by using a real calculator instead of my brain:

Assuming a "resort" is a "spring" then your method is correct (conservation of energy); I get $x=0.0115 m$ as my answer.

Comment: Could you please write down your computations? I do not know where I am wrong

Comment: i.e. you are correct, I just can't take square roots with my head very well :-P